# How to convert 4d array to 3d array subsetting on specific elements of one of the dimensions

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, average

Here is probably an easy question.. but I am really struggling so help is very much appreciated.

I have 4d data that I wish to transform into 3d data. The data has the following attributes:

```
lon <- 1:96  
lat <- 1:73  
lev <- 1:60  
tme <- 1:12

data <- array(runif(96*73*60*12), 
              dim=c(96,73,60,12) ) # fill with random test values
```

What I would like to do is calculate the mean of the first few levels (say 1:6). The new data would be of the form:

```
new.data <- array(96*73*12), dim=c(96,73,12) ) # again just test data
```

But would contain the mean of the first 5 levels of data. At the moment the only way I have been able to make it work is to write a rather inefficient loop which extracts each of the first 5 levels and divides the sum of those by 5 to get the mean.

I have tried:

```
new.data <- apply(data, c(1,2,4), mean)
```

Which nicely gives me the mean of ALL the vertical levels but can't understand how to subset the 3rd dimension to get an average of only a few! e.g.

```
new.data <- apply(data, c(1,2,3[1:5],4), mean) # which returns   
  Error in ds[-MARGIN] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I am desperate for some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` with indexing (the proper use of "[") should be enough for the `mean` of the first six levels of the third dimension if I understand your terminology:

```
> str(apply(data[,,1:6,] , c(1,2,4), FUN=mean) )
 num [1:96, 1:73, 1:12] 0.327 0.717 0.611 0.388 0.47 ...
```

This returns a 96 x 73 by 12 matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I though it would be simple but I think I got a bit confused!!

Comment: If this did in fact answer the question, you would be doing other readers a favor by hitting the checkmark. (I'm not really in need of extra points at the moment, but this will keep showing up as an "unanswered question" until you use the check.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @DWin, I would recommend the plyr package. The package provides `apply` like functions. The analgue of `apply` is the plyr function `aaply`. The first two letters of a plyr function specify the input and the output type, `aa` in this case, `array` and `array`.

```
> system.time(str(apply(data[,,1:6,], c(1,2,4), mean)))
 num [1:96, 1:73, 1:12] 0.389 0.157 0.437 0.703 0.61 ...
   user  system elapsed 
  2.180   0.004   2.184 
> Library(plyr)
> system.time(str(aaply(data[,,1:6,], c(1,2,4), mean)))
 num [1:96, 1:73, 1:12] 0.389 0.157 0.437 0.703 0.61 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ X1: chr [1:96] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ X2: chr [1:73] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ X3: chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
   user  system elapsed 
 40.243   0.016  40.262
```

In this example it is slower than `apply`, but there are a few advantages. The packages supports parallel processing, it also supports outputting the results to a `data.frame` or `list` (nice for plotting using `ggplot2`), and it can show a progress bar (nice for long running processes). Although in this case I'd still go for apply because of performance.

More information regarding the plyr package can be found in [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01). Maybe someone can comment on the poor performance of `aaply` in this example?